# How to send a list of changed fields via email in Wordpress

Tags: arrays, wordpress, notifications

I'm trying to create an email notification in Wordpress to alert the admin which fields a user has updated on their profile. These are custom fields, so I am using the 'updated_user_meta' function.

However this fires for each field that is updated and sends an individual email for each, as there could be up to 40 fields I ideally need a way of collecting these into an array and sending this instead.

Is there a different way of getting the data from this into 'build_email_notification', or a different action I can use that would be suitable for this?

'profile_update' looked like a promising alternative, but meta_input was empty.

```
add_action('updated_user_meta', 'get_meta_key', 10, 4);
function get_meta_key( $meta_id, $user_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value ) {

    $user = new WP_User($user_id);
    $username = $user->display_name;

    $returned_meta_key = $meta_key;

    build_email_notification($username, $returned_meta_key);
}


function build_email_notification($username, $returned_meta_key) {

    $userFields = array("field_01", "field_02", "field_03");
    
    $matchedFields = array();

    if(in_array($returned_meta_key, $userFields)) {
        $matchedFields[] = $returned_meta_key;
    }

    $to = get_bloginfo('admin_email');
    $subject = 'Profile Updated';
    $message = "Profile updated for user" . $username . ". The following fields were changed: ". implode(", ", $matchedFields);

    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
    
}
```